# How to add search field in rally grid / rally tree grid in rally custom report

Tags: rally, code-rally

I have a rally tree grid with portfolioitem/feature.I want a search field, so that if I input id there I should get data filter based on input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out this example in the docs as a starting point:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/filterable-tree-grid

That example is using an IterationComboBox to filter the grid, but you could just as easily use a regular TextField.  Here's the key part, where you'd handle the change event of the text field to filter the grid:

```
_onTextChanged: function(textField) {
    var treeGrid = this.down('rallytreegrid'),
        treeStore = treeGrid.getStore();

    treeStore.clearFilter(true);
    treeStore.filter(Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
        property: 'Name',
        operator: 'contains',
        value: textField.getValue()
    }));
}
```